# how i can display the availability times in Oracle Apex Calendar in a dynamic way based on the timezone of the user?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

In my Oracle Apex Application, I have a region with the type of calendar.
The calendar should visualize the available hours of certain services (availability times). For example,
from 09:00 am to 11:00 pm (Europe/Rome TimeZone).
For example, the problem occurs when someone logs into the application from the timezone Asia/Tokyo. In this case, the availability times are from 04:30 pm to 06:00 am and the calendar crashed.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

1. About my application

```
select * from v$version;

BANNER: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
BANNER_FULL: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.18.0.1.0
BANNER_LEGACY: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
CON_ID: 0
```

2. The function that I use to visualize the availability times is:

```
function ( pOptions) {
    pOptions.slotMinTime = "09:00:00"; // $v("P51000_ORA_INIZIO"); // hide slots before minTime
    pOptions.slotMaxTime = "23:00:00"; // $v("P51000_ORA_FINE"); // hide slots after maxTime
}
```

In case the start hour is 04:30 pm and the end hour is 06:00 am for example, is there a way to hide the unavailable hours dynamically (in our example the unavailable hours are from 06:00 am to 04:30 pm)?